# What implications are there for process builder or workflows when a record locked as part of an approval process?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, approval-process, knowledge

I am wanting to perform some automated process in Salesforce Knowledge, specifically around dates and time-based workflows or scheduled processes in process builder. However, when a user submits an article for approval I am not 100% clear on what happens if my approval process locks the record for editing. Can I still rely on my workflows or automated processes to update fields even if the record is locked for editing, or is it unreliable to depend on the automated field updates?

Note, that you can assume the user submitting the record for approval has all required edit object and field level permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can still rely on workflows or automated processes to update fields even if the record is locked by an Approval process.

Actually, Approval Process doesn't lock records for updates how for example FOR UPDATE SOQL does. Approval Process just prevents Users to update a record. And actually, not all users - Admins and whoever you specify still can edit the record.

Here's some doc on who can edit it: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_create_recordeditability.htm&type=5